# Elasticsearch - all replica shards are unassigned after configuring cluster awareness

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an (Elasticsearch) 7 node cluster:
6 nodes are data and master eligible nodes.
One is a witness and voting only node.

I have two datacenters, A1 and A2.

I have recently re-configured 6 of the data nodes with cluster routing allocation awareness, depending on the datacenter that they reside on:

**A1**

```
node.attr.ABC: A1
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: ABC
```

**A2**

```
node.attr.ABC: A2
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: ABC
```

Since I have set this and restarted all nodes, I see that all of my replica shards are now unassigned, and **ONLY** primary shards are assigned to nodes.

If I attempt to use *allocate_replica* and move one of the replicas to either node on either A1/A2 -

```
{
    "commands": [
        {
            "allocate_replica": {
                "index": "MY_INDEX",
                "shard": 0,
                "node": "node1.local"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I will get the error:

**node does not contain the awareness attribute [A1]; required attributes cluster setting**

How can I fix this and have my replica shards re-assigned correctly to the nodes?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the output you get from running this command `GET _nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.attributes,nodes.*.name,nodes.*.roles` ? And also `GET _cluster/allocation/explain`

Comment: Hey @Val - Sure here you are:
https://pastebin.com/raw/c736bwSX  and
https://pastebin.com/raw/Xm5Uzimi

Comment: Can you share the JSON please? it's not really legible that way. Also it seems the first output is missing the master-eligible node details

Comment: Sorry- here it is in JSON 

https://pastebin.com/raw/yP2LGzY9
and
https://pastebin.com/raw/56rzUXnn

Comment: Why does node A1P2 have a node attribute called `rack_id` instead of `ABC`?

Comment: Also 4 nodes have A1 and 2 nodes have A2

Comment: Hi Val - I was changing the cluster settings and had split it 4/2 for testing. 

I believe I have found the issue, after many days of trying different things. 

I believe in my case the issue was that the cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes was not set at a _cluster level :

Setting it at the cluster level :

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"persistent": {
"cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes" : "ABC"
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` provides the following clue:

> node does not contain the awareness attribute [A1]; required attributes cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes=A1

It seems that your cluster settings contains

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: A1
```

Instead of what you mentioned

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: ABC
```

Comment: Hi Val, would this be the same as setting:

I think I fixed the issues after many days of trying different things. 

I believe in my case the issue was that the cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes was not set at a _cluster level :

Setting it 

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"persistent": {
"cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes" : "ABC"
}
}

As this is what solved the issue for me. 

If so, please update your answer and I will mark it as  correct.

As mentioned in my case, issuing this immediately resolved the issue